# Work with ROS data in server side

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I need to implement a social network in the mobile application, in the application I will work with the local database, and then synchronize the data with the Realm Object Server. To handle some user activity, I will use a neural network written in python. How can I implement the work with the data on the server side, which are stored on the Realm Object Server for the needs of the neural network? Is this possible when using the free version (Developer Edition) of the Realm Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unfortunately not possible in the Developer Edition. The server side access functionality you need is only available in the Professional and EE versions.

You can read more here: https://realm.io/pricing